# Why are these two answers different?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was just looking over [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600360/integrate-fracz5z9) about how to integrate the function $$f(z) = \frac{z}{5z+9}$$

I notice that the two answers are actually different.  The top voted answer is $$\frac15z-\frac9{25}\ln\left|5z+9\right|+C$$

the other answer is $$z-\frac9{5}\ln\left|5z+9\right|+C$$

meaning they differ by a factor of $\frac 15$.

I don't see any mistakes in either answer.  So where's the difference between the two coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second answer is incorrect; the substitution $z\mapsto t-9$ is incorrectly done, when it should have been $z\mapsto \frac{t-9}{5}$, giving the extra factor of $\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: Ah.  Of course!  Thanks, I was just curious what the problem was. :)